# How to create a list of lists of tokens extracted in different sentences?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, nested-loops, nested-lists

I have a function which returns a list of elements and the len of each element of the list. I used that function in order to extract in the element of my past list, those which are present in a lexicon.

The problem I am facing is that the script below return a list of all the words present in my list of an element, but I want to return a list of words which are present in the lexicon for each elt of my past list. So that I will have a list of lists and those lists will contain only the word which appear in my lexicon for each particular element not a big ensemble of all the element.

My script is below and I tried two things : list-comprehension and loop but the two solutions always print me a list of all the words and not a list of lists of the word :

```py
def polarity_word(texte, listpos, listneg):

    lemme_sent, len_sent = lemmatisation(texte) # list of element(sentences lemmatized) 
    list_pos = []
    list_neg = []
    intersection = [w for w in listpos for elt in lemme_sent if w in elt ]
    
    #other way
    for elt in lemme_sent:
        for w in elt.split():
            if w in listpos:
                list_pos.append([w])
    
    # test data:
    lemme_sent =[ 'je vie manger et boire', 'je être bel et lui très beau']
    len_sent = [5, 7]
    list_pos = ['luire','manger','vie','soleil','boire', 'demain', 'soir', 'bel', 'temps', 'beau']
    
    print(intersection)
```

expected answer

```
[['vie', 'manger','boire'],['bel', 'beau']]
```

instead I have

```
[vie, manger','boire','bel','beau']
```

Comment: Please provide a non-empty list of your `list_pos` variable

Comment: @GustavRasmussen It is done

Comment: `[[w for w in elt.split() if w in list_pos] for elt in lemme_sent]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def polarity_word(texte, listpos, listneg):
    lemme_sent, len_sent = lemmatisation(texte)
    intersection=[]
    for elt in lemme_sent:
        intersection.append([word for word in listpos if word in elt])
    
    return intersection
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.